# Show LiteralControl in GridView dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, repeater

I create an html and set it to a literalControl.
Then I'm trying to insert this literalControl in a repeater's ItemTemplate.

But when I do this, it is seen as "System.Web.UI.LiteralControl" text, not the html inside.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:Repeater>
    //SomeColumns
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# GetPriorityBox(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate"),
                           DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EndDate") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It is seen from the browser like:

```
SomeColumn | SomeColumn | System.Web.UI.LiteralControl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the markup directly to the ItemTemplate. Change your `GetPriorityBox` method to return the Text property of the LiteralControl.

Answer (score 1):

Add a .Text to the end of that statement...  it won't inject a control using `<%# %>` notation.  It will only inject markup, so you have to inject the text only.  If you want the control injected, tap into ItemDataBound event, and programmably add the control.

HTH.